# Fetch Wroksheet and ListFeed from Google Spreadsheet Using PHP Curl

Tags: php, excel, curl, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am using this object-oriented php class for sending data to a Google Docs Spreadsheet -

http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/source/browse/trunk/includes/class.spreadsheet.php?spec=svn384&r=384

```
public function get()
{
    if(!empty($this->token)) {
        $url = $this->getPostUrl();
        $headers = array(
            "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->token,
            "GData-Version: 3.0",
            );
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);   
        $response = simplexml_load_string($response);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

I am calling this function from another file. like:

```
$doc = new spreadsheet();
$doc->authenticate("email", "pass");
$doc->setSpreadsheet("xxxxx");
$doc->setWorksheet("xxx");//here is static name of worksheet
var_dump($doc->get());
```

And Its working.

**Question** : I want to fetch all **worksheet**, **listfeed** of spreadsheet instead of passing is statically. because of my spreadsheet having lot of worksheet.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the URL? There is a URL that fetches the list of worksheets for a spreadsheet. Everything else is the same as far as I know. ... I am not sure what problem you want to solve.

Comment: I have url and every thing but when i fetching data i have to use this for selecting worksheet `$doc->setWorksheet("xxx");` i want to fetch all `worksheet` names of my `Shpreadsheet`.

Comment: did you see this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_information_about_worksheets it shows how.

Comment: Already seen it its not i want. I think you are not understanding @eddyparkinson

Comment: I understand what you want, but have no idea what problem you have hit. I assume you are no asking for someone to write the code

Comment: @eddyparkinson i want hint to find all worksheet's **ids or name** of spreadsheet.

Comment: Did you see the protocol tab in the docs  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#retrieving_information_about_worksheets

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of **worksheets**, use a URL like this:

```
"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + key + "/private/full"
```

To get a list of **spreadsheets**, use a URL like this:

```
"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full"
```

Some others:

```
public URL getSpreadsheetsUrl() throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL(
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
}

public URL getSpreadsheetUrl(String key) throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL(
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full/"
                    + key);
}

public URL getWorksheetsUrl(String key) throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + key
            + "/private/full");
}

public URL getWorksheetUrl(String key, String worksheetId)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + key
            + "/private/full/" + worksheetId);
}

public URL getCellsUrl(String key, String worksheetId)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/" + key
            + "/" + worksheetId + "/private/full");
}

public URL getCellUrl(String key, String worksheetId, String cellId)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/" + key
            + "/" + worksheetId + "/private/full/" + cellId);
}


public URL getTableUrl(String key, String worksheetId, String rowNumber)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/" + key
            + "/records/" + rowNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have created a function with return me array of all **worksheets** with **Id**.

Function Definition:

```
private function getWorkSheet() {

        $sheetArray = array();
        $url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?title=" . urlencode($this->spreadsheet);

        //echo "$url";exit;
        $headers = array(
                "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->token,
                "GData-Version: 3.0"
        );
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);



        if($status == 200) {
                $spreadsheetXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                //print_r($spreadsheetXml);
                if($spreadsheetXml->entry) {
                        $this->spreadsheetid = basename(trim($spreadsheetXml->entry[0]->id));
                        $url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" . $this->spreadsheetid . "/private/full";
                        if(!empty($this->worksheet))
                                $url .= "?title=" . $this->worksheet;

                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                        $response = curl_exec($curl);

                        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                        if($status == 200) {
                                $worksheetXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                                foreach($worksheetXml->entry as $entry)
                                {
                                    $temp = array('title'=>trim($entry->title),'id'=>basename(trim($entry->id)));
                                    array_push($sheetArray,$temp);
                                }
                                if($worksheetXml->entry)
                                        $this->worksheetid = basename(trim($worksheetXml->entry[0]->id));
                        }
                }
        }
        curl_close($curl);

        return ($sheetArray);
}

public function test()
{
    $sheet = $this->getWorkSheet();//calling my function here
    print_r($sheet);
}
```

If you want to fetch worksheet. All you need to put this function in [Class File](http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/source/browse/trunk/includes/class.spreadsheet.php?spec=svn384&r=384)